# Jquery code to check an element is exist in json

Tags: jquery, json

I want to check an element is exist in the json data
for that am doing

```
 $.get('/geteststatus', getdata, function (data) {

          if (data != "" || data[0].status ) {

});
```

where `getdata` is unique id

am getting this error

```
TypeError: data[0] is undefined


if (data != "" || data[0].status) {}
```

json data contains only one row value.it does not contain multiple values.so i used `data[0]` checking

json data

```
{"id" : "12" , "status" : "GC", "_id" : ObjectId("52f3045873e7e96b18000005") }
```

Comment: what is the format of `data` if it is an object then try `data.status` instead of `data[0].status`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Answer (score 1):

Since `data` is an object, you have to use

```
if(!data || data.status){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually good to add an escape clause--just exit if you don't get any data.

```
$.get('/geteststatus', getdata, function (data) {
  if (!data or data.length === 0) { return; }
  // process data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `typeof` operator:

e.g.

```
if(typeof data.status != "undefined") {
   //do something
}
```